# Laravel Version Cache with Laravel Mix Not Working

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I'm trying use laravel mix but in browser return error 404

**Laravel 5.6.4**

My .env APP_URL
APP_URL=http://localhost/base-site-template/public

My mix-manifest.json

```
{"/js/lib/echarts.js": "/js/lib/echarts.js?id=a24928e50f4d775d9e3e",
"/js/lib/moment.js": "/js/lib/moment.js?id=a3cde5d62118f1b1ac08",
"/js/lib/axios.js": "/js/lib/axios.js?id=1129cee8012a0ec7cb58",
"/css/lib/vuetify.css": "/css/lib/vuetify.css?id=c7533b5bc8f96cca4e90",
"/css/index.css": "/css/index.css?id=d41d8cd98f00b204e980",
"/css/template.css": "/css/template.css?id=c7533b5bc8f96cca4e90",
"/js/template.js": "/js/template.js?id=3213a53c38fb71543141",
"/js/lib/vue.js": "/js/lib/vue.js?id=e41f4d0b6a918ca9213d",
"/js/lib/lodash.js": "/js/lib/lodash.js?id=98dc43a5e921b41ef214",
"/js/lib/vee-validate.js": "/js/lib/vee-validate.js?id=bfc8600a0fc91c459f0e",
"/js/lib/vuetify.js": "/js/lib/vuetify.js?id=f0c3ad550b36770ee4c9",
"/js/index.js": "/js/index.js?id=5a79665b4d1331d942d7"}
```

[image: webpack.mix.js image - click here]

[image: Browser inspection image - click here]

[image: Browser view-source image - click here]

I'm trying to get css and js files using {{ mix('js/template.js') }}

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please don't use images, post actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resources are trying to be loaded from the root directory:

You're accessing the site at `/base-site-template/public` not `/`. So you'd have to access the files at `/base-site-template/public/js/index.js` not `/js/index.js`.

If you have your APP_URL set properly, you can use the asset() helper to prefix your APP_URL.

```
{{ asset(mix('js/template.js')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assets are placed into the `public/` directory when they're compiled, e.g:

```
public/js/lib/echarts.js
```

Your browser will treat relative requests beginning with `/` as relative to the base path which is `http://localhost/`. For example when you load the page `http://localhost/base-site-template/public` and it references `/js/lib/echarts.js` the browser will make this request:

```
http://localhost/js/lib/echarts.js
```

However that is not where your assets reside, your assets reside in:

```
http://localhost/base-site-template/public/js/lib/echarts.js
```

Therefore you will need to either:

1. Reference the assets using an absolute URL instead of a relative path
2. Tell clients browsers to use a different base path
3. Move your application to the base path

You can reference the assets with an absolute path using the [`asset` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset):

```
asset(mix('public/js/lib/echarts.js'));
```

You can tell the client browser to use a different base path using the [`base` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) in your documents `head`:

```
<base href="http://localhost/base-site-template/public/">
```